# && can not be applied to bool and int getvalueordefault

Tags: linq

I'm attempting to use `GetValueOrDefault` instead of null and not equal to 1 (code below will explain this).

Yet im getting the error:

> && cannot be applied to bool and int

I don't see the error here:

```
string[] arrItems = new string[] { 
    "Laptop", "Workstation", "Mobile","Monitor", "Other Peripheral", 
    "Home Printer", "Home Router", "Removable Device" };

var tblequipments = 
    from d in db.tblEquipments.Include(t => t.User).Include(t => t.ChangeLog)
    where (arrItems.Contains(d.AssetType)) &&
            (d.Development.GetValueOrDefault(0)) && 
            (d.Deleted == null || d.Deleted != 1 ) && 
            (d.Stock == null || d.Stock != 1 ) && 
            (d.DecommissionDate == Convert.ToDateTime("1900-01-01") || 
             d.DecommissionDate == Convert.ToDateTime("0001-01-01") || 
             d.DecommissionDate == null)  
    select d;
```

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory. `&&` is a boolean operator and both of its arguments have to be `bool`.

Comment: Perhaps GetValueOrDefault() does not return `bool`.

Comment: I think `(d.Development.GetValueOrDefault(0))` this is what cause the problem

Comment: Your code doesn't explain to me why you are not doing null and not equal to 1... If this works why not stick with it?

Comment: I thought it was cleaner and less code to not do null and not equal...

Comment: Unrelated, but move the `d.Decommissiondate == NULL` to the front of the expression with the other date comparisons.

Comment: @AlexW please mark one of the answers below as the accepted answer; otherwise, please let us know why these did not work (including any error messages).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [`HasValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094.aspx) instead of [`GetValueOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58x571cw.aspx) since the former returns a `bool` while the latter returns (in this case) an `int`:

```cs
d.Development.GetValueOrDefault(0)
```

should be:

```cs
d.Development.HasValue
```

Comment: (d.Development.HasValue != 1) && returns "=! cannot be applied to bool and int

Comment: Use just `d.Development.HasValue` or, if you prefer, `d.Development.HasValue == true`

Comment: If the value were false, wouldnt HasValue return true?

Answer (score 0):

That is because in .NET bools and ints are really different things. An int will never be false or true, it is just an int.
You could maybe do something like `(d.Development.GetValueOrDefault(0) != 0)` to make it boolean.

Comment: this returns LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 GetValueOrDefault(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.